# Can "too" be used with negative verb?

Tags: word-usage

> I'm busy today. Sasha is not here *too*

(Sentences are not really related)

http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/too-either.html says "either" should be used, but wanted confirmation.

Comment: That might work - but if it does, I wonder whether it's because *too* is licenced by / associated with the positive *is*, rather than the negative *is not here*.

Comment: Use of "too" in the sort of structure shown above is discouraged due to it's ambiguity, particularly in more complex sentences.

Comment: if you say that, i'll understand you - but i'll also infer that you are probably not a native speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I'm busy today. Sasha is not here, too."

If the meaning of the "too" is "This is something I'm telling you in addition to saying I'm busy", then "too" is okay.  But if the meaning is "I can't help you, and Sasha is also not available to help you," the "too" should be replaced by "either".

See Georgia Green, 1968, "On *too* and *either*, and not just on *too* and *either*, either." pp. 22-39, in *Papers from the fourth regional meeting of the Chicago Linguistic Society*.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know in negative sentences we use either or neither instead of too so the correct form of the above sentence is:
I'm busy today.Sasha is not here either